# Чем отличаются между собой URL, URI и URN?

Tags: url, терминология, uri

Чем отличаются между собой `URL` ("Uniform Resource Locator"), `URI` ("Uniform Resource Identifier ") и `URN` ("Uniform Resource Name")?

Comment: Гугл по `url uri urn` сразу приводит к [URI, URL, URN](http://handynotes.ru/2009/09/uri-url-urn.html)

Comment: есть ответ на SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/what-is-the-difference-between-a-uri-a-url-and-a-urn и есть ответ http://citforum.ru/internet/xml/uri/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URL` - местонахождение локации ресурса (локаций много может быть).
`URN` - местонахождение ресурса в локации.
`URI` - `URN` + `URL` (все данные в одном).

---

Например, ищем Библию:

`URL` - библиотека (а может книжный клуб, магазин, дом книгомана, etc.).
`URN` - данные относительно локации ^^^ (библиотека - ID, полка, ряд; книжный клуб - ISBN; дом книгомана - № комнаты, № книги в ряду).
`URI` - `URN` + `URL` (библиотека, пятый ряд, шестая полка).

Comment: Вообще, [тут в вике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI#.D0.A1.D0.B2.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8C_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B4.D1.83_URI.2C_URL_.D0.B8_URN) все довольно подробно изложено (даже с поясняющей картинкой и замечанием `что, возможно, термины URL и URN скоро уйдут в прошлое.`)

Comment: @avp, то, что где-то есть объяснение, не останавливает ленивых (?) пользователей. Я бы мог просто кинуть ссылку или копипастом, но это не поощряется.

Comment: Я просто подкинул желающим разбираться ссылку, где много чего об этих URL-ах (например, `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?` для разбора (ну, и на RFC ссылки и т.п. барахло))

Comment: @avp, таких желающих - дофига и больше. Только на "спросить".

Comment: Зачем спрашивать, если уже набрел на подходящую инфу?

Comment: @avp, в том-то и соль - только спросить, пусть набредают другие и подадут с примером.

Comment: Каждому свое...

Comment: @avp, только не переводите банальную лень в философский вопрос :)